# Can not put UiSearchBar on top of UiTextView

Tags: xamarin.ios

I've tried to put UiSearchBar on top of UiTextView. They are on UiVeiwController however when I put uiSearch, it remove UiTextView and show grey-line background. I tried to mixed things up via code. Unfortunately, it did not work.

Tool I use are MonoTouch and Interface Builder.

I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Please post the code you use, so we can check what is wrong. Combining the searchbar and textview is pretty common technique.